# WPF XML databind based on selection

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to change xml databinding dynamically based on selection.

Listbox binds with Movie Name and based on selection of movie name I need the corresponding Artists Names in datagrid.

Example - If we select Movie1 then I need to display Artist 1, Artis 2 and Artist 3

Plz help me how can I achieve above solution. Below is what I have tried.

Below is my xml

```
<Movies>
  <Movie Name = "Movie 1">
    <Artist Name="Artist 1"/>
    <Artist Name="Artist 2"/>
    <Artist Name="Artist 3"/>
  </Movie>
  <Movie Name = "Movie 2">
    <Artist Name="Artist 11"/>
    <Artist Name="Artist 22"/>
    <Artist Name="Artist 33"/>
  </Movie>
</Movies>
```

Below is my Xaml

```
<ListBox 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Width="100" 
    DataContext="{StaticResource MovieData}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Movies/Movie/@Name}"
    />

<DataGrid 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Width="200" 
    x:Name="dgridEmp" 
    DataContext="{StaticResource MovieData}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Movies/Movie/Artist}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Name" 
            Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" 
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me. I altered the bindings on the ListBox somewhat: Now the ListBox contains a list of Movie elements, but it only displays the @Name of each one.

The DataGrid uses the the selected Movie element from the ListBox as its DataContext, and then uses an XPath to pull all the Artist elements from that selected Movie.

```
<ListBox 
    Width="100" 
    x:Name="MovieSelector"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MovieData}, XPath=Movies/Movie}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    DisplayMemberPath="@Name"
    />

<DataGrid 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Width="200" 
    x:Name="dgridEmp" 
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MovieSelector}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Artist}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Name" 
            Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" 
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here's the XmlDataProvider I used:

```
<XmlDataProvider
    x:Key="MovieData"
    >
    <x:XData>
        <Movies xmlns="">
            <Movie Name="Movie 1">
                <Artist Name="Artist 1"/>
                <Artist Name="Artist 2"/>
                <Artist Name="Artist 3"/>
            </Movie>
            <Movie Name="Movie 2">
                <Artist Name="Artist 11"/>
                <Artist Name="Artist 22"/>
                <Artist Name="Artist 33"/>
                <Sleestak Name="Sleestak 44"/>
            </Movie>
        </Movies>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Plunkett. It's working. I got how to solve it.

Comment: @superuser Awesome. Working with XML in WPF controls is no fun.

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett Is this efficient solution or not?

Comment: @superuser Haven't the slightest idea.

Answer (score -1):

To show the artists you need to bind the `DataGrid` to the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox`. Something like this basic example should do the trick:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Movies"
         DataContext="{StaticResource MovieData}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Movies/Movie/@Name}"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ListBox_Movies, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Fruchtzwerg for your answer, but it's not working. Artist nodes are not binding to datagrid based on listbox selection

Comment: Maybe some other problem (bindings okay?), I runned the code a few seconds ago.

Comment: Can we achieve the solution using WPF databinding or do we need to write custom logic

Comment: No, you don't need some other logic. The code I posted is basically all you need.

Comment: In your code you didn't mention Artist node bind to grid.  How come datagrid knows which items to be bind. I tried your code It's not working.

Comment: By binding to the selected item of the listbox, you are binding to a movie. This movie contains the artists presented at the data grid. Just copy and paste my code to your project and improve the code step by step like needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145316/discussion-between-superuser-and-fruchtzwerg).